# Invisible markers in PDFs using pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, pdf, changes

I'm using `latexdiff` to show changes that I make in a large text (200+ pages). Most of my changes affect only a few pages though, so I don't want my readers to sift through 200 pages looking for the rare pages where isolated typo corrections were made: only about 30pp out of the 200 will contain changes.

I would like to:

1. Insert hidden PDF markers on pages where a changes occur
2. Compile with pdflatex
3. Run a script that filters out pages that don't contain the hidden PDF markers

   `book.tex -latexdiff-> book_diff.tex -pdftex-> 200pp.pdf -script-> 30pp.pdf`

Could someone recommend:

- a tex package for inserting "markers" of some sort in a PDF file
- a python package for reading PDFs (and looking for said markers)

Comment: The markers could perhaps be made with `pdfcomment` package, but I have no idea, whether there is an option to hide them.

Comment: @ChristianH. Wow, `pdfcomment` is the coolest package ever! It's dangerously cool---since I'm probably going to spend the rest of the day playing with it rather than working ;)

Comment: Yes, that package is very sophisticated. I found (but perhaps you already have done so too) that there is a `final` option which prevents the annotations to be set.

Comment: You should take a closer look on the package `changes`! It was made for exactly the case you have, and provides a `\listofchanges`. But, yes, `pdfcomment` is cool.

Comment: The original problem (first paragraph of question) is solved by using `--only-changes` option of `latexdiff-vc` (part of latexdiff package)

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was to use the I/O file operations, e.g. `\write` or `\immediate\write`, but it faced a known problem with floating objects and their behavior. I had also problem around floating objects with own counter when there was no `\global` prefix.

I rather used cross-references directly where a protected write is ensured. I can offer you this solution with the help of LuaTeX. The processed steps are:

- We typeset a regular document and mark a position. For purpose of this post it is a visible mark and it is a page number. The definition uses regular `\label` command with a certain prefix, e.g. `malipivo`. I named the file `filter.tex` and the command `\writeme`. The command uses own counter and that assures the uniqueness of the marker in the `\label` command.
- The `filter.tex` file is processed several times depending on an actual typeset material, in this example it is two times. After the first run we are getting a document with two red question marks (row 1 in the preview), after the second run we are getting cross-references correctly typeset (row 2 in the preview).

This is the code:

```
%! *latex filter.tex
%! Run me twice or even more times to get references right.
\def\myprefixis{malipivo}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[numbers]{kantlipsum}
\newcount\mycounter 
\mycounter=0
% Our own marker...
% Save the reference and mark it...
\def\writeme{%
\global\advance\mycounter by 1%
\label{\myprefixis\the\mycounter}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}%
\node[red,font=\bfseries\Huge,scale=4]{\pageref{\myprefixis\the\mycounter}};%
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
  }% End of \writeme...

\begin{document}
\section{My experiment}
\kant[1-2]\writeme
\kant[14]\writeme
\kant[15-16]\writeme
\kant[25]\writeme\ There is a typo and\writeme\ one more\writeme
\kant[26-32]\writeme
\kant[46]\writeme
\begin{figure}[p]
\kant[51] I am floating.\writeme
\end{figure}
\kant[52-61]\writeme
\end{document}
```

[image: filter.pdf after the first run]
[image: filter.pdf after the second run]

The content of the `filter.aux` file looks like this:

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}My experiment}{1}}
\newlabel{malipivo1}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{malipivo2}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{malipivo3}{{1}{2}}
\newlabel{malipivo4}{{1}{2}}
\newlabel{malipivo5}{{1}{2}}
\newlabel{malipivo6}{{1}{2}}
\newlabel{malipivo7}{{1}{4}}
\newlabel{malipivo8}{{1}{4}}
\newlabel{malipivo10}{{1}{7}}
\newlabel{malipivo9}{{1}{8}}
```

You can actually see, that there is some floating object as numbers are swapped to their page number counterparts (`malipivo10`<->`malipivo9`; `7`<->`8`). We need to process this auxiliary file somehow and extract the pages from `filter.pdf`. I used LuaTeX and the `pdfpages` package.

- At first I thought that I needed to sort the lines, but it seems it is not necessary, it is already sorted by the page numbers, not by the markers.
- However, I needed to extract lines with `malipivo` prefix included and skip the others. I used `string.find` from LuaTeX. There is a note in the terminal from this step saying `Testing note on page 1...`.
- Then I needed to extract page numbers to get `1 1 2 2 2 2 4 4 7 8`, I used the `string.gsub`function.
- I had to assure that each page will be included only once, so we should get this sequence of numbers `1 2 4 7 8` after removing duplicates.
- My next step was to add commas, I did that while concatenating the temporary string. We are getting to `1,2,4,7,8`.
- The rest was relatively easy. I made a LaTeX command out of it to get `\includepdf[pages={1,2,4,7,8},fitpaper]{filter.pdf}` and shipped it to the document body.

I created a simple function in LuaTeX named `testme` with two parameters, the first parameter is asking for the tested file (`filter`), the code uses its `aux` and `pdf` files, and the second parameter is asking for a prefix we were using (in theory, there could be more prefixes), I used `malipivo`. The actual typesetting is done by `\directlua{testme("filter","malipivo")}`.

I enclose the code (`filtered.tex`) to be run via `lualatex` once and finally a preview of selected pages (`filtered.pdf`) which were marked in the original code (`filter.tex`).

```
%! lualatex filtered.tex
%! run me only once
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
function testme (filtering, thekey)
-- Initializing variables...
local myinput=filtering..".aux" -- Where are the reference?
local myinputpdf=filtering..".pdf" -- Where are the real PDF pages?
local mylines="" -- List of pages to get is?
local mycount=0 -- How many tested reference do we have?
local lastcount="" -- What is the previous reference?
-- The core of the function...
for mylinetemp in io.lines(myinput) do -- Read input file line by line
  test=string.find(mylinetemp,thekey) -- Is a unique key involved? 
  if test~=nil then -- Yes, the key is present there...
    myline=string.gsub(mylinetemp,"\\newlabel{"..thekey..".-}{{.-}{(.-)}}", "%1", 1) -- Find a group with page reference.
    print("Testing note on page "..myline.."...") -- Print information to the terminal
    mycount=mycount+1 -- Increase a number of tested references
    if mycount==1 then -- Save the first value as the starting value
      mylines=myline -- Start the resulting string
      lastcount=myline -- Remember the last occurance
    else -- Add value to the list if not already stored in the list
      if lastcount~=myline then -- But only if last two values differ (aka uniq)
        mylines=mylines..","..myline -- Add comma and value to the string (aka join)
        lastcount=myline -- Remember this occurance as the last one for next testing
      end -- of if not lastcount
    end -- of if mycount
  end -- of if thekey is involved
end -- of myline
-- Print the results and generate PDF via regular typesetting...
local keyresult="\\includepdf[pages={"..mylines.."},fitpaper]{"..myinputpdf.."}"
print(keyresult)
tex.print(keyresult)
end -- of function testme
\end{luacode*}

% The tested file, e.g. filter.{aux,pdf}, and its reference label prefix.
\directlua{testme("filter","malipivo")}

\end{document}
```

[image: filtered.pdf]

Comment: Thx for your solution. I had never seen luatex before, and I find it cool to be able to script with the text document. I don't have luatex on my machine right now though, so I wasn't able to test it.

Comment: Not at all! You can use only the first part/{TeX file} and then manually (or in other program) handle the `aux` file. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I wrote a first draft of a working pipeline.

- As per @ChristianH's suggestion, I used [pdfcomment](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment)
- For the script, I used:

  - [pdfminer](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/) to read the PDF annotations
  - [pdfrw](https://code.google.com/p/pdfrw/) to write the selected pages

The code is here: 
https://gist.github.com/ivanistheone/219dad11a30efef82b7e